# How to have auto increment in ClickHouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want a column to have a unique value in every insertion. In SQL we can have this using autoincrement, in Clickhouse can we have this functionality using any type like auto increment or any other? I am new to Clickhouse so there may be a terminology mistake.

Comment: There are no foreign keys in Clickhouse. It is not a traditional relational database.

Answer (score 10):

There is no server-provided auto-increment in ClickHouse.

As stated by other answers, UUID's is the way to go.

Instead, use *generateUUIDv4()*  (see documentation [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/uuid/))

Sample output

```
SELECT generateUUIDv4();
```

Use during insert

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (generateUUIDv4(), ...);
```

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing like auto increment in ClickHouse.

If you need unique value, use UUID. It [works much better for distributed systems](https://coder.today/software-engineer-from-monolith-to-cloud-auto-increment-to-uuid-a62f92f387c4) than just auto incremented value

So you can simply generate random Uint64 and convert it to UUID

```
SELECT toUUID(rand64());
```

With insert it would look similar to this

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (toUUID(rand64()), ...);
```

Comment: it is not working. Error gives: DB::Exception: Element of set in IN or VALUES is not a constant expression: toUUID

Comment: @Sakezzz just tested and works. Provide more info so I can help.

Comment: might be in new versions though

Comment: Tested in latest version to Oct 2018 (not sure what it was) and in v20.12 now